# I want to place an ImageView overlapping another ImageView with left and top corner starting in center of first ImageView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

[image: Overlapping ImageViews]

I would like to position an ImageView (Blue) with its upper left corner starting in center of a second ImageView (Red).  Preferably within a ConstraintLayout. The first red ImageView has undermined size since it will be stretched to fill a percentage of the screen.  The challenge is locating the center of the first red ImageView. I tried using Guidelines, Barriers but they all expect top/bottom/left/right references.  How can this be done using XML layouts?

Answer (score 1):

A `gone` view will have zero width and zero height but can be positioned at the center of the red rectangle. The top/left of the blue rectangle can then be placed at this center point by constraining its top and left to the center widget.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/centerPoint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/centerPoint" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/centerPoint"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

The placement can be made anywhere within the red rectangle by changing the vertical and horizontal bias of the center widget.

Comment: That's a clever trick I hadn't considered. I'll give it a try!